# Access the printed output of a function call

Tags: python, python-2.7, stdout

Part of my script calls a function from (let's call it `foo`) another module (written by someone else a long time ago, and I don't want to start modifying it now).
`foo` writes interesting things to `stdout` (but returns `None`), in part, by calling other functions as well.
I want to access these interesting things that `foo` writes to `stdout`.

As far as I know, `subprocess` is meant to call commands that I would normally call from the command line. Is there an equivalent for python functions that I would call from my script?

I'm on python2.7, if it matters

Comment: I don't know Python well enough, but with Ruby, I would do this by changing stdout to a buffer that I control, calling the function, restoring stdout, and then manipulating the data in the buffer as needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @JimDeville commented, you can swap stdout:

```
#!python2.7
import io
import sys

def foo():
    print 'hello, world!'

capture = io.BytesIO()
save,sys.stdout = sys.stdout,capture
foo()
sys.stdout = save
print capture.getvalue()
```

Output:

```
hello, world!
```

Python 3 version uses `io.StringIO` instead due to `stdout` expected to be a Unicode stream:

```
#!python3
import io
import sys

def foo():
    print('hello, world!')

capture = io.StringIO()
save,sys.stdout = sys.stdout,capture
foo()
sys.stdout = save
print(capture.getvalue())
```

Comment: Is there an equivalent for python 2.7 or will this work out of the box?

Comment: Just noticed that.  Updated for 2.7.  Needs `BytesIO` instead, or the older `StringIO.StringIO` that works with <2.7.

Comment: Am not able to make this solution work with Python 3.7. :(

Comment: Found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16571630/5232681

Comment: @AshishJain Updated with Python 3 example.