# How to capture stdout output from a Python function call?

Tags: python, stdout, capture

I'm using a Python library that does something to an object

```py
do_something(my_object)
```

and changes it. While doing so, it prints some statistics to stdout, and I'd like to get a grip on this information. The proper solution would be to change `do_something()` to return the relevant information,

```py
out = do_something(my_object)
```

but it will be a while before the devs of `do_something()` get to this issue. As a workaround, I thought about parsing whatever `do_something()` writes to stdout.

How can I capture stdout output between two points in the code, e.g.,

```py
start_capturing()
do_something(my_object)
out = end_capturing()
```

?

Comment: possible duplicate of [capturing dis.dis results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12111717/capturing-dis-dis-results)

Comment: My answer in the linked question applies here as well.

Comment: I tried to do that once and the best answer I found was:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/3113913/1330293

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3378965/355230).

Comment: See also: [Redirect stdout to a file in Python? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675728/redirect-stdout-to-a-file-in-python)

Answer (score 268, accepted):

Try this context manager:

```
from io import StringIO 
import sys

class Capturing(list):
    def __enter__(self):
        self._stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = self._stringio = StringIO()
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.extend(self._stringio.getvalue().splitlines())
        del self._stringio    # free up some memory
        sys.stdout = self._stdout
```

Usage:

```
with Capturing() as output:
    do_something(my_object)
```

`output` is now a list containing the lines printed by the function call.

Advanced usage:

What may not be obvious is that this can be done more than once and the results concatenated:

```
with Capturing() as output:
    print('hello world')

print('displays on screen')

with Capturing(output) as output:  # note the constructor argument
    print('hello world2')

print('done')
print('output:', output)
```

Output:

```
displays on screen                     
done                                   
output: ['hello world', 'hello world2']
```

*Update*: They added `redirect_stdout()` to [`contextlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) in Python 3.4 (along with `redirect_stderr()`). So you could use `io.StringIO` with that to achieve a similar result (though `Capturing` being a list as well as a context manager is arguably more convenient).

Comment: Thanks! And thanks for adding the advanced section... I originally used a slice assignment to stick the captured text into the list, then I bonked myself in the head and used `.extend()` instead so it could be used concatenatively, just as you noticed.  :-)

Comment: P.S. If it's going to be used repeatedly, I'd suggest adding a `self._stringio.truncate(0)` after the `self.extend()` call in the `__exit__()` method to release some of the memory held by the `_stringio` member.

Comment: @martineau A new `StringIO` instance will be created each time the context manager is used anyway, and the old one will go away at that time, but you could set `self._stringio` to `None` (or `del` it) in `__exit__()` if the interim memory usage is a problem.

Comment: Oh, yeah, that's right...my mistake. The previous contents were interfering with something experimental I was doing to the first instance before the second was created, which (mis)led me into thinking the results would accumulate. The fact that both have the same name compounded the illusion. ;-)

Comment: @kindall That's a very smart solution! Works like a charm, even if in my case I had to redirect `stderr` as well, as I wanted to capture `argsparse` error message.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. For Python 3, use `from io import StringIO` instead of first line in context manager.

Comment: Is this thread-safe? What happens if some other thread/call uses print() while do_something runs?

Comment: Answering myself.. Not thread-safe. If another thread calls for print, it will trickle into 'output'

Comment: Yep, not thread-safe, although printing to stdout can itself get a little wonky with threads anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work with C modules (such as `fontforge`)

Comment: Is the `del` statement necessary?  I would have thought that after `__exit__` is finished, everything goes out of scope and will be promptly garbage collected.

Comment: Why would it go out of scope?

Comment: This answer will not work for output from C shared libraries, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24277488/in-python-how-to-capture-the-stdout-from-a-c-shared-library-to-a-variable/29834357) instead.

Comment: is it possible to send the `output ` to another object in real-time ?

Answer (score 194):

In python >= 3.4, contextlib contains a [`redirect_stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout) context manager. It can be used to answer your question like so:

```
import io
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

f = io.StringIO()
with redirect_stdout(f):
    do_something(my_object)
out = f.getvalue()
```

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout):

> Context manager for temporarily redirecting sys.stdout to another file
> or file-like object.
>
> This tool adds flexibility to existing functions or classes whose
> output is hardwired to stdout.
>
> For example, the output of help() normally is sent to sys.stdout. You
> can capture that output in a string by redirecting the output to an
> io.StringIO object:

```
  f = io.StringIO() 
  with redirect_stdout(f):
      help(pow) 
  s = f.getvalue()
```

> To send the output of help() to a file on disk, redirect the output to
> a regular file:
>
> ```
>  with open('help.txt', 'w') as f:
>      with redirect_stdout(f):
>          help(pow)
> ```
>
> To send the output of help() to sys.stderr:
>
> ```
> with redirect_stdout(sys.stderr):
>     help(pow)
> ```
>
> Note that the global side effect on sys.stdout means that this context
> manager is not suitable for use in library code and most threaded
> applications. It also has no effect on the output of subprocesses.
> However, it is still a useful approach for many utility scripts.
>
> This context manager is reentrant.

Comment: when tried `f = io.StringIO()
        with redirect_stdout(f):
            logger = getLogger('test_logger')
            logger.debug('Test debug message')
        out = f.getvalue()

        self.assertEqual(out, 'DEBUG:test_logger:Test debug message')` . It gives me an error: `AssertionError: '' != 'Test debug message'`

Comment: which means i did something wrong or it could not catch stdout log.

Comment: @EzizDurdyyev, `logger.debug` doesn't write to stdout by default. If you replace your log call with `print()` you should see the message.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I do make it write to stdout like so: `stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)`. And add that handler to my logger. so it should write to stdout and `redirect_stdout` should catch it, right?

Comment: I suspect the issue is with the way you've configured your logger. I would verify that it prints to stdout without the redirect_stdout. If it does, maybe the buffer isn't being flushed until the context manager exits.

Comment: When your code does not redirect either std_out or std_err (I mean: I still have output to console and nothing is saved to disk), what does it mean?

Comment: 3.7.12 works for me in jupyter but not shell

Comment: What if we want to capture both stdout and stderr

Comment: @MohitC see the similar [`redirect_stderr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stderr)

Answer (score 4):

Here is an async solution using file pipes.

```
import threading
import sys
import os

class Capturing():
    def __init__(self):
        self._stdout = None
        self._stderr = None
        self._r = None
        self._w = None
        self._thread = None
        self._on_readline_cb = None

    def _handler(self):
        while not self._w.closed:
            try:
                while True:
                    line = self._r.readline()
                    if len(line) == 0: break
                    if self._on_readline_cb: self._on_readline_cb(line)
            except:
                break

    def print(self, s, end=""):
        print(s, file=self._stdout, end=end)

    def on_readline(self, callback):
        self._on_readline_cb = callback

    def start(self):
        self._stdout = sys.stdout
        self._stderr = sys.stderr
        r, w = os.pipe()
        r, w = os.fdopen(r, 'r'), os.fdopen(w, 'w', 1)
        self._r = r
        self._w = w
        sys.stdout = self._w
        sys.stderr = self._w
        self._thread = threading.Thread(target=self._handler)
        self._thread.start()

    def stop(self):
        self._w.close()
        if self._thread: self._thread.join()
        self._r.close()
        sys.stdout = self._stdout
        sys.stderr = self._stderr
```

Example usage:

```
from Capturing import *
import time

capturing = Capturing()

def on_read(line):
    # do something with the line
    capturing.print("got line: "+line)

capturing.on_readline(on_read)
capturing.start()
print("hello 1")
time.sleep(1)
print("hello 2")
time.sleep(1)
print("hello 3")
capturing.stop()
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on `kindall` and `ForeverWintr`'s answer.

I create `redirect_stdout` function for `Python<3.4`:

```py
import io
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def redirect_stdout(f):
    try:
        _stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = f
        yield
    finally:
        sys.stdout = _stdout


f = io.StringIO()
with redirect_stdout(f):
    do_something()
out = f.getvalue()
```

Answer (score 3):

Also drawing on @kindall and @ForeveWintr's answers, here's a class that accomplishes this. The main difference from previous answers is that this captures it *as a string*, not as a `StringIO` object, which is much more convenient to work with!

```py
import io
from collections import UserString
from contextlib import redirect_stdout

class capture(UserString, str, redirect_stdout):
    '''
    Captures stdout (e.g., from ``print()``) as a variable.

    Based on ``contextlib.redirect_stdout``, but saves the user the trouble of
    defining and reading from an IO stream. Useful for testing the output of functions
    that are supposed to print certain output.
    '''

    def __init__(self, seq='', *args, **kwargs):
        self._io = io.StringIO()
        UserString.__init__(self, seq=seq, *args, **kwargs)
        redirect_stdout.__init__(self, self._io)
        return

    def __enter__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        redirect_stdout.__enter__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.data += self._io.getvalue()
        redirect_stdout.__exit__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return

    def start(self):
        self.__enter__()
        return self

    def stop(self):
        self.__exit__(None, None, None)
        return
```

Examples:

```py
# Using with...as
with capture() as txt1:
    print('Assign these lines')
    print('to a variable')

# Using start()...stop()
txt2 = capture().start()
print('This works')
print('the same way')
txt2.stop()

print('Saved in txt1:')
print(txt1)
print('Saved in txt2:')
print(txt2)
```

This is implemented in [Sciris](https://github.com/sciris/sciris) as [sc.capture()](https://sciris.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/sciris.sc_printing.capture.html).