# Where do we insert an ag-grid enterprice license when using it via justpy?

Tags: ag-grid, justpy

Somehow this seem to involve this

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/licensing/

And this

https://github.com/justpy-org/justpy/search?q=ag-grid-enterprise&type=

But I just cant seem to figure it out where to put the license in the python script or in the .js file just yet?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score -1):

Modify this html template

https://github.com/justpy-org/justpy/blob/master/justpy/templates/optional_packages.html

to include your license in the script after the enterprise ag is loaded.

```
{%- if options.aggrid_enterprise %}
{%- if not options.no_internet %}
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/ag-grid-enterprise.min.js"></script>
{%- else %}
<script src="/templates/local/ag-grid-enterprise.js"></script>
<script>
agGrid.LicenseManager.setLicenseKey("your licene key");
</script>
{%- endif %}
{%- endif %}
```

You can find the path to this file in your local environment by importing justpy or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17453261/how-to-find-out-the-python-library-installation-path)

Comment: Don't do this. It won't be supported in the future. https://github.com/justpy-org/justpy/issues/588 is the way to go