# Python call function from module in a subprocess

Tags: python, function, module, subprocess

I would like to retrieve the stdout, stderr and resultcode of a module function called from the main program. I thought subprocess was the key, but I don't succeed submitting the module function to subprocess.

What I have:

```
#my_module.py
def run(args):
    do stuff
    print this
    return THAT
if name == "__main__":
    args = read_args()
    run(args)
```

.

```
#my_main_script.py
import subprocess as sp
import my_module
p = sp.Popen(my_module.run(args), stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
result = p.resultcode
```

What occurs:
Apparently the subprocess module does something with THAT returned from the my_module.run() provoking the crash:

if `THAT = list_of_lists` error: `AttributeError: "sublist" object has no attribute rfind`

if `THAT = ["a","b",0]` error: `TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings`
if `THAT = ["a","b"]` error: `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

So subprocess apparently wants THAT to be a list containing path to files ???

Comment: What is your read_args() definition? I'm attempting something similar but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 3):

You are not using subprocess in the right way :

```
sp.Popen(["./my_module.py", "arg1", "arg2"], stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
```

By the way, you wouldn't get any resultcode if you does not exit properly your program with the `sys.exit(retcode)` function.

The final scripts would look like this :

```
#my_module.py
def run(args):
    do stuff
    print this
    return THAT

if name == "__main__":
    import sys
    args = read_args()
    sys.exit(run(args))

#my_main_script.py
import subprocess as sp

p = sp.Popen(["./my_module.py", "arg1", "arg2"], stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
result = p.returncode
```

Comment: how will the module receive the arguments then? (they already are in the argparse format)
Can't I just launch the run function ?

Comment: Edited. Sorry i forgot this part.

Comment: So I should reconvert all arguments from my argparser to a string format, and then run the main with the converted arguments ? No way at all to simply call a function in sp.Popen() ?

Comment: Forget what I say before about another solution. I *think* it's the right way to deal with it. Maybe someone else will come with another possibility, but currently I only see this one.

Comment: Else, you can do it this way : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571150/how-to-capture-stdout-output-from-a-python-function-call

Comment: Perfect ! This last option suits perfectly my necessity !
Im still wondering what the subprocess was expecting as a return from my function... :/
Thanks for your help !

Comment: I think you don't really get what subprocess is. Do you want me to explain it ?