# Saving Lua output to the Python string

Tags: python, python-3.x, lua, lupa

I have a Lua expression, which can print some string. For example: `print(1+2)`. Then, I call this expression in Python 3 using [Lupa](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lupa) library:

```
import lupa

lua = lupa.LuaRuntime(unpack_returned_tuples=True)
res = lua.eval('print(1+2)')
```

Of course, `res` is `None` because this expression returns nothing. But **I need to catch the output and save in the variable**.

Is this possible? How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16571630/3005167)? I do not know if `lupa` cares about `sys.stdout`, but it's worth a try.

Comment: @kazemakase, I have just tried it but it doesn't work for me. Firstly, I replaced `cStringIO` to `io` because I've working on Python 3. So, when I ran following code: `with Capturing() as output:
            lua.eval('print(1+2)')
        print(output)`, **I've got an empty list output**.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used Python, but I think you need to do this:

```
import lupa

lua = lupa.LuaRuntime(unpack_returned_tuples=True)
res = lua.eval('1+2')
```

*res* should now be 3, which you can print from Python.
If you want Lua to print it instead, you'll have to use execute:

```
res = lua.execute('local v = 1+2 print(v) return v')
```

*(Based on similar questions that had those code examples)*