# overwriting output of function in terminal on same line

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a function, for example

```
def f(x):
    for i in range(x):
        print i
```

Without making any addition in f(x) function, is it possible to overwrite the  terminal line during run? For example, in my case it shows like this:

```
print f(5)
```

output is:

```
1
2
3
4
```

but I want it to overwrite and instead print like this:

```
print f(5)

4
```

Please keep in mind that I cannot modify inside f(x) function.

Comment: Maybe printing control character help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571150/how-to-capture-stdout-output-from-a-python-function-call     + retrieve last line from captured stdout and print it. There is no straightforward way.

Comment: the printing part is done in the function, so why again `print f(5)`.

Answer (score 0):

In general, no; but depending on what the "terminal" is assumed
to be, maybe.   Many terminal windows emulate the ancient cursor
positioning commands from one or more "glass tty" terminals. In
which case, if you assume you know what terminal is being emulated,
you can send cursor positioning commands to move back to the previous
before calling f.

Answer (score 0):

Since `print` issues a newline, and you cannot go back after that, you have to prevent at all costs that a newline char to be issued in the terminal.

You can do it by redirecting `sys.stdout`. `print` will output to your new stream. In your stream, remove the linefeed and add a carriage return. Done

```
import sys


def f(x):
    for i in range(x):
        print i

class fake():
    def __init__(self):
        self.__out = sys.stdout
    def write(self,x):
        r = self.__out.write(x.replace("\n","")+"\r")
        self.__out.flush()  # flush like if we wrote a newline
        return r


sys.stdout=fake()

f(5)
```

Result:

- on a terminal (windows or Linux): only 4 is shown
- redirecting to a file: we see all numbers separated by `\r` chars

Ok it's a hack but we cannot modify `f` and we did not... Mission accomplished.

It may be useful to restore `sys.stdout` to its original value once we're done.

Comment: Jean-François Fabre, when i run your suggested code. it print nothing. :(

Comment: can you redirect to a file and see what's in it. Works fine here (windows).

Comment: @ShahbazAhmed I have modified the `write` routine so it performs a `flush`, which may be needed in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to print only the last line, you can pipe the output and use tail command to retrieve only the last word.

Useful link: https://kb.iu.edu/d/acrj

Comment: Hi Ganesh, welcome to SO and thank you for your answer. As links can change over time, would you mind editing your post (edit link below it) to add in the pertintent details of your suggested solution? You can still include the link as context and attribution, but it would be helpful to keep the key details alive here. Thank you!