# get output of the python code

Tags: python, tkinter

I have `ScrolledText` in `Tkiner` application ,in which i am supposed to write the python code in it and i have one button,by pressing that i send those lines of code to `InteractiveInterpreter().runcode("code as a string")`

This `runcode()` method return the `NoneType` object and shows output on the `cmd`
but i want output in string format, i tried using `exec()` but it didn't work for me.There is some way to do that?

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
from ScrolledText import *
from code import InteractiveInterpreter
interpreter = InteractiveInterpreter()

def go(event):
    print(interpreter.runcode(textPad.get('1.0', END+'-1c')))

root = tk.Tk()
textPad = ScrolledText(root,width=100,height=100)
textPad.focus_set()
b2=tk.Button(root, text ="Run",width=34,height=3)
b2.pack()
b2.bind('<Button-1>', go)
textPad.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Help usually follows more quickly if you provide the [smallest *working* example of your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate the problem you're facing. Please add some code that does this.

Comment: did you try print?

Comment: print(InteractiveInterpreter().runcode("code as a string")) this returns None @ChipJust

Comment: You might want to try the technique in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16571630/7432

Comment: i did add code,now check that out @RonNorris

Comment: i already saw that one,but i don't have enough brain to implement that in my code.I really found that one confusing. @BryanOakley