# External library uses print instead of return

Tags: python

I have a problem with an external library that I use in my script.

I execute a function from this library, but the function prints the output directly. However, I need the output to check if there is a specific string in it.

How can I ensure that the output of the function in the external library comes in a variable so that I can make the comparisons with the string?

Comment: How tied are you to that external library? It sounds pretty badly designed. Are there any ways you can access the value more directly?

Comment: This answer helped me with a similar issue in the past: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16571630/6321559

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exchange sys.stdout with your buffer temporarily, and then check the buffer.

```
def external_method():
  print ("print something out, don't return")

class MyBuffer(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.buffer = []
  def write(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.buffer.append(args)

import sys
old_stdout = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = MyBuffer()
external_method()
my_buffer, sys.stdout = sys.stdout, old_stdout
print (my_buffer.buffer)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really have no other choice, you could redirect `stdout` when you call the library. Here's a piece of code adapted from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45899925/6419007) :

```
def some_library():
    print("Should probably return instead of print.")

import sys
from io import StringIO

class redirected_stdout:
    def __init__(self):
        self._stdout = None
        self._string_io = None

    def __enter__(self):
        self._stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = self._string_io = StringIO()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        sys.stdout = self._stdout

    @property
    def string(self):
        return self._string_io.getvalue()

with redirected_stdout() as out:
    some_library()
    result = out.string

print("return" in result)
# True
```

It would be much cleaner to modify the library, though.