# Assign the output of a print function to variable

Tags: python

I've got this code which outputs a print of user inputted terms to console

```py
x = input("Input x: ")
y = input("Input y: ")
z = input("Input z: ")

xS = x.split(", ")
yS = y.split(", ")
zS = z.split(", ")

[print('"{}"'.format(i), end=" ") for i in xS] + [print('"{}"'.format(i), end=" ") for i in yS] + [print('-"{}"'.format(i), end=" ") for i in zS]
```

where the inputs can be like `he, haha, ho ho, he he he`,
and the print function outputs like so when `x = he`, `y = haha, ho ho`, and `z = he he he`

```py
"he" "haha" "ho ho" -"he he he"
```

Does anyone know a way to assign the output of the print (`"he" "haha" "ho ho" -"he he he"`) to a variable like `j`?

**CLARIFICATION EDIT:** the double quotes in the print output aren't saying that its a string. This whole thing is basically taking in user input, splitting it up with `,` as a delimiter, and adding the `""` to the start and end of each separated term which end up as `"term"`, that finally gets put into a search engine that works similar to Google's

Comment: what is x, y and z in `he, haha, ho ho, he he he`?

Comment: `print` returns `None`, if you want the result, don't use `print`.  Also don't use list comprehensions for side-effects

Comment: you could just add them to list or tuple as follows `j = [x, y, z]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to capture stdout output from a Python function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571150/how-to-capture-stdout-output-from-a-python-function-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use a print statement to help with your string formatting. As noted, `print()` will always return `None`. You could instead just format your strings as follows:

```
x = "he"
y = "haha, ho ho" 
z = "he he he"

xS = x.split(", ")
yS = y.split(", ")
zS = z.split(", ")

j = ' '.join([f'"{i}"' for i in xS] + [f'"{i}"' for i in yS] + [f'-"{i}"' for i in zS])

print(j)
```

This would display:

```
"he" "haha" "ho ho" -"he he he"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
>>> x = ['he'];y = 'haha, ho ho'.split(',');z = ['he he he']  
>>> x+y+['-']+z  
['he', 'haha', ' ho ho', '-', 'he he he']
>>> var = " ".join(x+y+['-']+z)
```

---

**Output:**

```
>>> print(var)    
'he haha  ho ho - he he he'
```

**Edit 1:**

```
>>> " ".join('"{}"'.format(el) if el is not '-' else el for el in x+y+['-']+z)        
'"he" "haha" " ho ho" - "he he he"'
```

Comment: output needs to have the variable inside double quotes, in this case `he he he` needs to end up as `-"he he he"` and the same for the other variables.

Comment: @w4tchdoge Is that what you are expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
x = input("Input x: ")
y = input("Input y: ")
z = input("Input z: ")

xS = x.split(", ")
yS = y.split(", ")
zS = z.split(", ")
j = ('"{}"'.format(' '.join(xS)), '"{}"'.format(' '.join(yS)), '-"{}"'.format(' '.join(zS)))

print (j)
```

output:

```
Input x: ha, ha
Input y: he, he, he
Input z: huh, hih
('"ha ha"', '"he he he"', '-"huh hih"')
```

Comment: output needs to have the variable inside double quotes, in this case `heh, huh` needs to end up as `-"heh, huh"` and the same for the other variables

Comment: just added the edit, does it fit your criteria now?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend constructing the string yourself then printing it.

```
xS = "he"
yS = "haha, ho ho"
zS = "he he he"

j = " ".join( [ '"' + x.strip() + '"' for y in [xS,yS,zS] for x in y.split(',') ] )

print( j )
```

Output:

```
'"he" "haha" "ho ho" "he he he"'
```