# Can't manipulate content of a string. Ex.: Check If it has numbers or not, replace characters and cia

Tags: python, string, windows, stdout, python-3.7

I'm storing the result of a external .py file in a variable called `output`. The standard stdout is, for example: `['229', '229', '229', '230', '230', '230']`. To do so, after some research, I implemented this class:

```
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO

class Capturing(list):
    def __enter__(self):
        self._stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = self._stringio = StringIO()
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.extend(self._stringio.getvalue().splitlines())
        del self._stringio    # free up some memory
        sys.stdout = self._stdout
```

When I check the `output` content with `print(output)` it seems fine. The stdout of my other .py file was stored.

My problem: I can't do almost anything with the `output` content.

Ex.:

1- When I try to replace characters: `AttributeError: 'Capturing' object has no attribute 'replace'`,

2- When I try to do the same above, but using "translate": `AttributeError: 'Capturing' object has no attribute 'translate'`

3- Check if it has numbers:

```
if any(char in '0123456789' for char in output):
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

This ^ works fine if I manually assign values to `output`.

I expect some explanation why this is happening. I'm feeling that is something really basic. I'm just started with python.

Comment: Why do you expect `Capturing` to have `str` methods when you subclass `list`?

Comment: Check how to use Capturing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571150/how-to-capture-stdout-output-from-a-python-function-call

Comment: Thank you, guys. Helped me a lot. I knew it was something basic.