# Is there a way to get a list of all pep8 violations using pycodestyle?

Tags: python, pep8, pycodestyle

I want to check a file using `pycodestyle`. I've tried using what [their docs](https://pycodestyle.pycqa.org/en/latest/advanced.html) say:

```
import pycodestyle

fchecker = pycodestyle.Checker('testsuite/E27.py')
file_errors = fchecker.check_all()
# I took off the show_source=True and the final print
```

It prints the errors, but `file_errors` is the NUMBER of errors, not the errors themselves. I want the errors to be returned in a list. How can I do that using pycodestyle?

### More details

`pycodestyle` is a module that checks code against the [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines. Usually, it is used with the command line, but I want to automate it by putting it into a script. Using [the docs](https://pycodestyle.pycqa.org/en/latest/advanced.html), you get:

```
import pycodestyle

fchecker = pycodestyle.Checker('testsuite/E27.py', show_source=True)
file_errors = fchecker.check_all()

print("Found %s errors (and warnings)" % file_errors)
```

This prints the errors and the total amount of errors. However, `file_errors` is not a list- it's the number of errors.

I would want a way to get a list from `pycodestyle.Checker` (or any thing in pycodestyle). How can I do that?

**What I've done**: I've looked on google, and skimmed `pycodestyle`'s docs, but nothing is mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From skimming the [source code](https://pycodestyle.pycqa.org/en/latest/_modules/pycodestyle.html), it doesn't seem to have any way to return the errors, just print them. So you can [capture its stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16571150/4518341) instead.

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
import io

f = io.StringIO()  # Dummy file
with redirect_stdout(f):
    file_errors = fchecker.check_all()
out = f.getvalue().splitlines()  # Get list of lines from the dummy file

print(file_errors, out)
```

<sup>*This code is based on [ForeverWintr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1286571/foreverwintr)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40984270/4518341)*</sup>

For example, run it on a file like this:

```
s  = 0
```

Output:

```
1 ['tmp.py:1:2: E221 multiple spaces before operator']
```