# Create a string on the output. The output is a NoneType object

Tags: python, nonetype

I am running Aspect-Based-Sentiment-Analysis. And I get the output. I want to get this output as a string. I spent several hours in googling how to refer to the output and not only to see the output when I run a code. Maybe I don't comprehend something in Python basics and need huge support on that.

The code I am talking about is as follows:

```
absa.summary(money)
```

The output that i receive from this code:

```
Sentiment.positive for "money"
Scores (neutral/negative/positive): [0.001 0.006 0.993]
None
```

I checked the type of this object and it says Nonetype:

```
type(absa.summary(money))
Sentiment.positive for "money"
Scores (neutral/negative/positive): [0.001 0.006 0.993]
NoneType
```

How can I extract the text from the output as a string? Any ideas? I will provide any additional info when it is needed.

Comment: Can you post more/all of your code? I believe ABSA is using tensorflow in the background, so the "summary" results are likely tied to the object returned from < absa.load() >.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the command is just printing the output to `stdout` instead of acutally returning an object containing the information you are looking for. You may want to try and capture `stdout` while running the function. The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571150/how-to-capture-stdout-output-from-a-python-function-call) should be helpful.

Comment: You are referring to a helpful answer, but your answer might be more useful if you encapsulated a working code segment.