# How to create log of entire python script / or print functions and store in a file

Tags: python, logging

I want to create a log of all the print functions and save it in a file which I can display on Flask HTML page. The script is very complex but some what like below:

```py
def main():

   def one function():
    # do something
     print(response)
   def other function():
     print(response2)
......

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: Can you use shell redirection? For example, `python myscript.py > output.txt`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to capture stdout output from a Python function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571150/how-to-capture-stdout-output-from-a-python-function-call)