# Code action based on print statements from code in python?

Tags: python

I am running in a loop an astronomical script written by another person. This is a minimal version of my loop:

```
from astro_script_file import some_astro_class

for file_name in ['file_1.txt', 'file_2.txt', 'file_n.txt']:
    some_astro_class.function_1(file_name)
```

When executing the above `function_1` makes calculations based on the input txt-file and prints an output to the screen of the kind `number of populated galaxies: some-number`. The number of galaxies is declining with each iteration of my loop and I want to break the loop when the number reaches 0. For that I need to somehow read in the print statement or load it into a variable. I don't want to alter the astronomical script itself that I am provided with, instead I want to tinker only outside of it when I am executing the script.

Is this possible? Is there some way to load print statements when they get executed?

Comment: Shouldn't `function_1` handle this case? I don't have more info but I imagine it will run forever without it.

Comment: Isn't it possible at all to alter `function_1`? reading the output seems like overkill compare to simply returning the number, and I don't know how you are going to save the number in a variable without editing the script.

Comment: @Guy Thanks! No, `function_1` doesn't handle the case of galaxy counts, it just spits them out. It's because `function_1` was not intended by the author to be be used in a loop. Even I most of the time don't use it in a loop. But for a special task now I have to. And the loop doesn't run forever, it runs until all files that I provide are covered

Comment: To read the output you can probably do something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/40984270/5168011

Answer (score -1):

```
while true:
example = 5:
if example = 0:
print("Done")
else:
example =- 1
```

But i guess it would be different with files.

Comment: What this got to do with the question?

Comment: And pay attention to code formatting in your answers.

Comment: Aside from being irrelevant, it's also broken and will not even compile if the indentation is fixed... Please avoid submitting broken code, especially when it's extremely simple to test.