# Is it possible to thread-safe redirect logging.StreamHandler()?

Tags: python, multithreading, stdout

For print messages I use:

```py
import contextlib
 
def thread_proof_print_capture(thread_number):
    path = f'path/to/some/dir/thread_{thread_number}.txt'
    with open(path, 'w') as f:
        with contextlib.redirect_stdout(f):
            print('Hello, World')
    # the file thread_{thread_number}.txt contains all prints that would've been printed in this thread
```

[How to thread-safely capture stdout output from a function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76858868/how-to-thread-safely-capture-stdout-output-from-a-function-call/76860353#76860353)

But I also would like to redirect log messages that are printed to stdout. For logging I use:

```py
LOGGING_HANDLER_LIST = [logging.StreamHandler(), logging.FileHandler("test.log")]  # stdout and to file
LOGGER_FORMAT = "%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(format=LOGGER_FORMAT, handlers=LOGGING_HANDLER_LIST)
log = logging.getLogger("test")
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

I initially thought that the stdout redirect would also redirect `logging.StreamHandler()` but that's not happening. Is there a way to also redirect what gets logged to stdout?

The main intend is to make a program that was not intended to run multi-threaded to log each thread to its separate file without having to change it much. The program itself works with a global logger so it would work if you start it as a sub-processes but as they are run as threads within python the global variables would overwrite each other, resulting in not separated log files.