# Collocation output to a variable

Tags: python, nltk

I am trying to put in my collocation results into a variable.

I am able to do this

```
print(corpus.collocations())
```

and get the output on the console...

but when I do

```
my_results = corpus.collocations()
print(type(corpus.collocations()))
```

I get the output as

```
<class 'NoneType'>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this module, but perhaps this function `collocations()` is printing its results instead of returning them?

Comment: I think that the problem is that `collocations()` prints to screen, rather than returns. You might benefit from [this question I asked a while ago](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14422797/198633)

Answer (score 1):

Use collocation_list() instead of collocations().

In your case -

`myresults = corpus.collocations_list()`

myresults has a a list of tuples. The tuples consists of consecutive words for all collocations